Is this an error in RFC 6386 (VP8 Data Format and Decoding Guide)?
In Section 19.2 of RFC 6386 (“VP8 Data Format and Decoding Guide”), which describes the VP8 frame header, on p. 129, in the description of token_prob_update(), the type of the flag coeff_prob_update_flag is given as L(1), which, according to the table in Section 8 on p. 25, means that this is a single literal bit that should be read with a 50/50 probability coded as 128 (see also read_literal on the preceding page).
But other parts of the RFC say that these flags are actually read with predetermined probabilities other than 128: Section 13.4 (“Token Probability Updates”) on p. 68 specifies these probabilities in the array coeff_update_probs, and the function decode_entropy_header in the reference implementation (file dixie.c, p. 138/139) uses them (in the array k_coeff_entropy_update_probs) to decode these flags.
I checked the current version of libwebp; it follows the reference implementation and uses these predetermined probabilities. According to the table on p. 25, the type of such a flag should be specified as B(p) (where p is the probability), not as L(1).
This version of the RFC that includes verified errata still says L(1).
Is this an error in the specification, or am I missing something?
Update: I’ve now reported this as an erratum here. I also found these search results, which list three errata (in addition to the ones I just submitted) as “reported” (as opposed to “verified”); one dates back to 2018, so it seems there’s a backlog of errata that aren’t being processed.
